# ExtJS Grid adds two rows on .insert();

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using an ExtJS editorgrid and in some cases when I try to insert a row into the 
datastore the grid seems to over write the next row with a copy of the new row.

This is using ExtJS version 3.2.1

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Clone',
        handler: function (btn)
        {
            var data, wizard, store, record, grid =          btn.findParentByType('editorgrid');
            store = grid.getStore();
            if (grid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection())
            {
                data = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().data;
                data.iid = -1;
                record = new store.recordType(data);
                Ext.data.Record.id(record);
                store.insert(0,[record]);
                grid.getSelectionModel().selectRecords([record], false);
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overwrite situation presented here maybe caused by the existing of double id on your clone operation. Because your new cloned record seem don't have an unique id.

```
Ext.data.Record.id(record); // return generated unique string id that you never use
record.id = Ext.data.Record.id(record); // here is the different
```

Try this

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Clone',
        handler: function (btn)
        {
            var data, wizard, store, record, grid =          btn.findParentByType('editorgrid');
            store = grid.getStore();
            if (grid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection())
            {
                data = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().data;
                data.iid = -1;
                record = new store.recordType(data);
                record.id = Ext.data.Record.id(record); // here is the different
                store.insert(0,[record]);
                grid.getSelectionModel().selectRecords([record], false);
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
data = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().data;
```

Was part of the problem, both records pointed to the same raw data, I changed it to make a copy of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much this helped a lot to get better ideas to resolve copy a row
and we can do multiple rows copy this way 
 and very simple.

```
var selectedRows = selectedModel.getSelection();
for ( var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
 var data = selectedRows[i].data; 
 data.iid=-1;
 store.insert(0,[data]);
}
```

So a record in inserted on top of the grid, as we already checked.